# QGIS expression with overlay-fuction: filter-condition based on comparison of attributes from two layers

Tags: qgis, expression, overlay, geometry-generator, syntax

In QGIS 3.18, I have two point layers: `layer_1` with attribute `id_1` and `layer_2` with `id_2`. I want to use the `overlay_nearest` function: `overlay_nearest(layer[,expression][,filter][,limit=1][,max_distance][,cache=false])`

Applied on `layer_1`, I want to get for each point on `layer_1` all points on `layer_2` where `id_2` has a different value from `id_1` (to connect them by a line). However, I can't find out how the syntax of the filter-argument works, how to refer to attribute values of two different layers for comparison.

The basic expression is: `overlay_nearest( 'layer_2', $geometry, [filter])`

How is the syntax of the `[filter]` part? `filter:="id1" <> "id2"` obviously doesn't work. `$id <> "id2"` and  `$id <> "id1"` don't work either.

---

**Edit**: see this example here to make the idea clearer.

- Red dots = `layer1`, labeled with `id1`
- White dots = `layer2`, labeled with `id2`

Each red point should be connected to it's nearest white point, **except** when their id is the same. However, on the upper left (red arrows), you see that 12 is connected to 12, 17 to 17:

[image]

The expression used in geometry generator on `layer1` for this is as follows (the filter condition is on lines 6 to 18):

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        overlay_nearest( 
            'layer2', 
            $geometry, 
            filter:=attribute (
                get_feature_by_id (
                    'layer1', 
                    $id
                ), 
                'id1'
            ) <> attribute (
                get_feature_by_id (
                    'layer2', 
                    $id
                ), 
                'id2'
            ) , 
            limit:=1
        ),
        make_line (
            $geometry, 
            @element
        )
    )
)
```

***Edit**

See more here in the responses to the feature request, especially:

> The purpose of the filter parameter is to reduce the dataset (layer2)
> to use for research, so it's applied before it proceeds to any overlay
> test

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43146

Comment: Came accross the same issue recently. Not sure if its a bug or just me not understanding how this works...

Comment: Somehow consoling to see others with the same problem :-) So let's hope we get cleared the mystery here...

Comment: and something like `filter:=eval('"id2" <>' || "id1"')` (just an idea, not tested)

Comment: @J. Monticolo: unfortunately, neither `filter:=eval("id_2" || '<>' || "id_1")` nor if both terms in the brackets are in single quotes `'` does work. At least the syntax doesn't produce an error, but returns an empty result, even if there are corresponding features. I guess the problem is somehow to tell QGIS which attribute comes from which layer.

Comment: `filter:=attribute (get_feature_by_id ('layer_1', $id), 'id_1') <> "id_2"` seems to work - have to check it, will come back later.

Comment: Unfortunately not, see edited question

Comment: Let's hope your bounty (thanks, by the way!), which is active for some days to come, brings further attention to this problem and maybe even a solution - otherwise indeed it would be good to report it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tested some configurations, tried to understand how it works. **So** ! I figure it out.

The scope of the `filter` parameter in the expression function of `overlay_nearest` is purely the layer set in the `layer` argument, *as if* you put this expression in the `layer` select by expression.

To achieve your goal, I came up with another solution. Instead of select the nearest `$geometry` of the other layer, I selected the nearest `$currentfeature`. And in the end, instead of building a line directly, I put an `if` condition to return a `NULL` geometry if the nearest `layer_2` feature `id2` equals the current `id1`.

```sql
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_nearest(
            'layer_2',
            $currentfeature,
            limit:=1
        ),
        if(
            condition:=attribute(@element, 'id2') = "id1",
            result_when_true:=NULL,
            result_when_false:=make_line(geometry(@element), $geometry)
        )
    )
)
```

| **EDIT** : display more connections / increase the `overlay_nearest` limit |
| --- |

With the QGIS expression above, if you increase the `overlay_nearest` limit, say **2** instead of **1**, if one of the collected geometries is `NULL` because it meets the condition, it nullifies all the geometries and it's not what we want.

Just replace in this case the `NULL` condition result with a zero length line :

```sql
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_nearest(
            'layer_2',
            $currentfeature,
            limit:=2 -- update here
        ),
        if(
            condition:=attribute(@element, 'id2') = "id1",
            result_when_true:=make_line($geometry, $geometry), -- update here
            result_when_false:=make_line(geometry(@element), $geometry)
        )
    )
)
```

| **EDIT** : each `layer_1` point have the same number of lines |
| --- |

> *Hey ! Yes it works but when `layer_1.id1 = layer_2.id2` I got only one line for this point ...*

Okay ... I heard you, you are right, GIS is a demanding discipline so I'm reviewing my copy !

To achieve this, I defined a variable, placed on top for easy access, `lines_per_point`. You can set the number of lines per point, here **2**.

With the comment of @MrXsquared, I used `array_filter` instead an `if` condition in the `array_for_each`, it drops all *NULL* values.

But ! I increased by **1** the `overlay_nearest` limit of features returned (I considered that `layer_2` identifiants are unique, so filter can drop for one `layer_1` point only one line maximum (when `layer_1.id1 = layer_2.id2`)).

Ok, it returns arrays of lenght 2 or 3. Here I used `array_slice` to get only the two first features (beware, the slice doesn't work as a Python list, it includes the 2 bounds), so [0, 1], so [0, *lines_per_point* - 1].

We have now an array of length 2 with `layer_2` features. So, I applied an `array_foreach` to create the line with `make_line(geometry(@element), $geometry)`.

(Obviously, you'll get different number of lines for each `layer_1` points if the lines per point equals the number of features of `layer_2`)

The QGIS expression below :

```sql
with_variable('lines_per_point', 2,  -- adjust here
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        array_slice(
            array_filter(
                overlay_nearest(
                    'layer_2',
                    $currentfeature,
                    limit:=@lines_per_point + 1
                ),
                attribute(@element,'id2') <> "id1"
            ),
            0, @lines_per_point - 1
        ),
        make_line(geometry(@element), $geometry)
    )
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! Indeed, the filter of `overlay_nearest` works on the layer set in the `layer` argument - but it seems strictly limited to it. Not even addressin explicitely another layer with `get_feature_by_id` does work and I'm still not sure if it is by purpose, a but or if I miss something.

Comment: Your solution is great as a workaround for the missing abilitiy of the `overlay_nearest` filter to compare attributes from different layers. It works great! However I was wondering now to increase the number of connections, let's say to 2. See the screenshot: normally 2 lines are drawn. But if nearest point has the same id as the current point, no line at all is drawn: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AclCk.png - shuldn't just one line be drawn? See yellow area: there is correctly no connection from 2 to 2 and 1/1. But 1 and 2 should each be connected to 7 as 2nd nearest. Have to figure out why not.

Comment: If I just use the `overlay_nearest` part of the expression with `limit:=2` on `layer1` (red), it clearly shows in the preview for `feature 2` on `layer 1` two matching features on `layer2` (white): `feature 2` and `feature 7`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQijs.png - applying the same to the geometry generator, no line at all is drawn: line from 2 to 2 is filtered out (correct), but line from 2 to 7 does not appear, either.

Comment: @Babel: see my edit.

Comment: great! may I suggest to use `array_filter()` instead of `array_foreach(if())` to prevent the array from containing NULL values at all, like `array_filter(overlay_nearest('layer_2',$currentfeature,limit:=2),attribute(@element,'id2') <> "id1")`. Only disadvantage is, that you will only get 1 result at the end if the other one is filtered out.

Comment: @J. Monticolo: Thanks, that is great and works perfect! I thus upvoted the question, but will wait to accept it. I still hope to get an "authoritative" answer regarding the filter-condition of `overlay_nearest` - if there is definitely no way to use in the way I intended to and we have to use some workaround for this.

Comment: @MrXsquared: great comment, would be worth posting it as a separate answer. In the comments, it gets overlooked

Comment: New edit, new solution !

Comment: @J. Monticolo: great job, indeed! And replacing the second argument of the `with_variable` from `2` to `aggregate( 'layer2', 'count',$id)`, one can draw a line from every point of layer 1 to every point of layer 2, **except** when their id has the same value.

Answer (score 7):

With QGIS 3.22.1 and 3.16.15 and newer versions, it will be possible to use a much simpler and more efficient expression to achieve the expected result:

```
make_line(
    eval(
        'overlay_nearest(\'layer2\',
        $geometry,
        filter:=id2<>' || "id1" || ' )' 
        )[0],
    $geometry
    )
```

This expression also works with the current QGIS 3.23.0-master (since commit [768ccc6](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/768ccc698fa1de02579e3d15fef2c4ec289482ce))

Comment: Thanks so much for the patch and sharing

Comment: So if I understood correctly, with QGIS 3.22.0 it does not yet work, right? Just asking because I thought point releases do not add functionality, only bug fixes, but this seems to be wrong at least in this case. Anyway, this is indeed great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Babel it was a bug (an incorrect caching) that prevented the above expression to work.

Comment: The above expression is a valid expression in QGIS < 3.22.1, but it gives incorrect results. In QGIS 3.22.1 it will give the correct results.

Comment: The fix was back-ported to 3.16, so it will be also available since QGIS 3.16.15 onward.

Comment: Is it really necessary to `eval()` here (which is not very elegant imo) or was that just your approach in the example?

Comment: @bugmenot123 unfortunately it is necessary for now. This is a "workaround" made possible by PR https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/45744. See the feature request https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43146.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from this dataset [1] taken from here [0], this expression works for me: (QGIS 3.22.0)

```
collect_geometries(
         make_line(
             $geometry,
             geometry(get_feature('layer2','id2',
                         attribute( 
                         array_filter( 
                         overlay_nearest('layer2',$currentfeature,limit:=-1), 
                attribute(@element,'id2' ) != "id1")[0], 'id2' ))))
                  )
```

[image]

[0] https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43146#issuecomment-836472827

[1] https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/af5cHue6P3NA9xM

Comment: Indeed great to see how many good answers this question gets. A pity I can accept only one, so I'll leave the initial accept.