# Dissolve consecutive touching lines segments where common value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, aggregate, geometry-by-expression

[image: Dissolve Problem]

I am trying to dissolve the grey line layer where the field "dis" ( "anzahl" || '-' || "heizlast") has the same value and the segments are touching ( end_point touches the next segments start_point).

The dissolve function ( with keep disjoint features separate) is not working for this specific example becuse the orange segment and the blue one touch in the end_point. For this kind of solution I thought of geometry by expression:

```
collect_geometries(
 aggregate(
            layer:='Aggregated',
            aggregate:='array_agg',  --or 'collect' I am not quite sure
            expression:=$geometry,
            filter:=intersects(end_point(@geometry), start_point(geometry(@parent))) 
            AND "dis"  = attribute(  @feature , 'dis')
        ))
```

However the result is not what I am expecting. I think I read it somewhere that the aggregate function is not working well with the geometry by expression. I am not quite sure that my function is good enough , maybe I need some kind of iteration where more than two segments are compared ? like array_foreach ? I am stuck ....

I just found quite the same question here and tried the expression:
[Merging line segments using length rules in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416444/merging-line-segments-using-length-rules-in-qgis)

```
union (
        $geometry, 
        eval (
            'overlay_touches (''line'', $geometry, filter:=id= '  || id || ' and $id <> '  || $id  || ' )[0]'
        )
    )
```

The problem is that the expression is combining two segments at a time and also generates NULL geometries and duplicates. The expression needs a finishing touch for iterating and collecting all the touching lines where the end_point match the start_point and has the same value. Also the expression that I copied is referencing to "id" ( int) and my field for dissolving "dis" is of type string wich is not working in this context.Here is the part where I need some help.

[image: Result overlay_touches]

**Retrospectively**
[Dissolving line segments in QGIS if they touch and fall within same class?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173446/dissolving-line-segments-in-qgis-if-they-touch-and-fall-within-same-class?rq=1)

I also found the exact the same question ( 8 years old) but the solution by the author himself can not be applicable in this case. I need a more general function otherwise it complicate the situation with the so called "higher" order and splitting by lines.

I tried something similar by myself:

Dissolve ( field: "dis" and keep disjoint feature separate )

In this case the 3 segments ( blue marked ) are being merged because they are touching. I can then generate the vertices of the segments and categorize this by the next expression:

```
count('Vertices', group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry))
```

[image: Dissolving_Disjoint]

Afterwards I would split the undesired merged segments from before with the vertices that are different then 1 and get what I need. BUT choosing this path it has again an undesirable effect for the remaining splitted lines which will changed the direction.

[image: DirectionProblem]

Comment: If you have access to PostGIS, a directed [`st_lineMerge`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) could be used

Comment: Maybe possible to recreate that in spatialite (Virtual Layer) using a self join of the layer if OP can add an unique id column? Some version of `SELECT t1.dis, ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(t1.geometry, t2.geometry)) as geometry FROM layer AS t1 JOIN layer AS t2 ON t1.start_point = t2.end_point AND t1.id <> t2.id GROUP BY t1.dis` ? maybe the group by needs to be separate - won't be in front of a PC for a while to test

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I don't have access to PostGIS yet and a virtual layer is not gonna help me neither because I need to implement it for automatisation into the graphical model :( I was hopping for a "field calculator" solution / or something suitable for the model.

Comment: FYI, the graphical modeler has an "Execute SQL" algorithm in the Vector General group, which runs on any source data, not just PostGIS. GDAL also has a similar on under Vector Miscellaneous.

Comment: You absolutely right, I kind of forgot about the SQL in the graphical model. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my previous answer because it didn't work in all cases.

You have to create for this example an field "dissolveID":

[image]

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # MultiLineString

anzahl_idx = layer.fields().indexOf('anzahl') # int 
heizlast_idx = layer.fields().indexOf('heizlast') # int
dissolveID_idx = layer.fields().indexOf('dissolveID') # int

f_endpoint = QgsFeature()
neighbour_startpoint = QgsFeature()

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        f['dissolveID'] = NULL
        layer.updateFeature(f)

dissolveID = 0

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        f_refValue = str(f.attributes()[anzahl_idx]) + str(f.attributes()[heizlast_idx])
        f_id = f.id()
        f_dissolveID = f.attributes()[dissolveID_idx]
        f_points = [point for point in f.geometry().asMultiPolyline()]
        endpoint = f_points[0][-1]
        f_endpoint.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(endpoint))
        
        for neighbour in layer.getFeatures():
            f_dissolveID = f.attributes()[dissolveID_idx]
            neighbour_dissolveID = neighbour.attributes()[dissolveID_idx]
            neighbour_refValue = str(neighbour.attributes()[anzahl_idx]) + str(neighbour.attributes()[heizlast_idx])
            neighbour_id = neighbour.id()
            neighbour_points = [p for p in neighbour.geometry().asMultiPolyline()]
            startpoint = neighbour_points[0][0]
            neighbour_startpoint.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(startpoint))
            if neighbour_startpoint.geometry().intersects(f_endpoint.geometry()) and  \
                neighbour_refValue == f_refValue and \
                neighbour_id != f_id :
                if f_dissolveID == NULL and \
                    neighbour_dissolveID == NULL:
                    f['dissolveID'] = dissolveID
                    neighbour['dissolveID'] = dissolveID
                    layer.updateFeature(f)
                    layer.updateFeature(neighbour)
                    f_dissolveID = f.attributes()[dissolveID_idx]
                    neighbour_dissolveID = neighbour.attributes()[dissolveID_idx]
                elif f_dissolveID == NULL and \
                    neighbour_dissolveID != NULL:
                    f['dissolveID'] = neighbour_dissolveID
                    layer.updateFeature(f)
                    f_dissolveID = f.attributes()[dissolveID_idx]
                elif f_dissolveID != NULL and \
                    neighbour_dissolveID == NULL:
                    neighbour['dissolveID'] = f_dissolveID
                    layer.updateFeature(neighbour)
                    neighbour_dissolveID = neighbour.attributes()[dissolveID_idx]
                    
        dissolveID += 1
```

[image]

The code above checks if you have the **same attributes** and it is **connected endpoint - startpoint**. In some cases you could want to check azimut - angle to check a significant *change in direction*. Because in my example from above a simple endpoint to startpoint connection will also dissolve Line ID 3 and Line ID 6 if the have the same attributes. Therefore you must calculate the difference between the azimuth of the feature and the neighbour AND define a *tolerance*. This could be achieved with:

```
startpoint.azimuth(endpoint)
```

[image]

You could verify your defined tolerance in the first if statement.

[image]

Another thing that could be necessary to verify is the amount of nodes at the endpoint of the feature. 1 would be an endpoint. 2 a line and more than 2 a kind of crossing.

```
count = 0
for i in layer.getFeatures():
    if f_endpoint.geometry().intersects(i.geometry()):
        count += 1
```

[image]

And again you could verify your accepted node count in the first if statement.

If you want you can implement the python script as function in the graphic modeler.

Comment: I am grateful for your answer but unfortunately I am not so into the python scripts…. Not yet. I was hopping for a singular advanced expression. Nevertheless I would give it a try and extract the knowledge out of it. Meanwhile I managed to resolve my problem by my own by adding some additional fields which lead to distinctive groups of the lines that I can later on dissolve as needed.