# Variable is not recognize in QGIS expression using overlay_nearest function

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-variable

### Context

I use an expression with Geometry Generator in QGIS 3.22 to connect each point with the nearest point that has the value of `2` for the attribute field called `value`. This works fine using this expression:

```
make_line (
    $geometry,
    overlay_nearest (
        @layer, 
        $geometry, 
        filter:= value = 2
    )[0]
)
```

### The problem

However, I want to replace the value of `2` with a variable. However, this does not work - the following expression returns just `NULL`. When I replace @number (line 9) with `2`, everything is correct again:

```
with_variable(
    'number',
    2,
    make_line (
        $geometry,
        overlay_nearest (
            @layer, 
            $geometry, 
            filter:= value = @number
        )[0]
    )
)
```

*Using a value of 2, lines are correctly drawn. If I replace `2` by `@number`, output is just `NULL`:*
[image]

### The question

Obviously, the variable is not correctly recognized. Why is that / how can this be solved? I'm specifically interested in solving this using a variable.

There is a workaround (see next), still, I'm interested why that does not work as expected.

### A workaround

A workaround based on [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415248/88814) is to use a string with `eval()` function.

```
with_variable(
    'number',
    2,
    make_line (
        $geometry,
        eval (
            'overlay_nearest (
                @layer, 
                $geometry, 
                filter:= value ='  || @number || ')[0]')
    )
)
```

[image]