# Snap points based on attribute QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, expression, snapping

I'd like to snap the blue points to the nearest yellow point based on an attribute they share on QGIS, this attribute is their suburb, I've tried by using the tool "geometry by expression"  running the following expression:

```
closest_point(
 geometry(
   get_feature(
     'yellowpoints',
     'suburb',
     attribute(
       $currentfeature,
       'suburb'
     )
   )
 ),
 $geometry
)
```

However, It snaps the blue points only to one per each suburb.

[image]

Does anyone know any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome, maybe here you find the solution:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391120/qgis-expression-with-overlay-fuction-filter-condition-based-on-comparison-of-at

Answer (score 3):

QGIS documentation for [get_feature()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#get-feature) function says:

> Returns the first feature of a layer matching a given attribute value.

That's why you get always the same point. Try with an aggregate, something like this:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='yellowpoints',
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:=$geometry,
    filter:="suburb" = attribute(
        @parent,
        'suburb'
    ),
    order_by:=distance(
        geometry(@parent),
        $geometry
    )
)[-1]
```

Other option is.

```
closest_point(
    aggregate(
        layer:='yellowpoints',
        aggregate:='collect',
        expression:=$geometry,
        filter:="suburb" = attribute(
            @parent,
            'suburb'
        )
    ),
    $geometry
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the processing tool "Snap Vertices To Nearest Points By Condition" from [ProcessX Plug-In](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/).

Choose your `blue points` as `Source Layer`, your `yellow points` layer as `Points Layer`, select `all options` in `Snap Vertices` and your two `suburb indicator fields` as condition with `=` as `comparison operator`:

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this Plug-In.*