# Using filter expressions in QGIS calculator with overlay_nearest

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-expression

I have a layer 'Points' and a layer 'Lines'.
Both layers contain an 'ID' attribute, which relate (but it's an m x n relation)

I'm trying to get the point position "along" a line, and I can do this with the field calculator in the 'Points' layer:

`line_locate_point(overlay_nearest('Lines', $geometry)[0], $geometry)`

But because there are overlapping lines, I need to use the "ID" attribute to limit the selection.

How can I add a `filter` expression to the `overlay_nearest` function saying something like `Point.ID = Line.ID`? My main issue is that I don't know how to differ the "current point" from the "line in the function" in the expression.

Comment: Did you already try to use [`array_filter()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-filter) with an adequate expression for `overlay_nearest('Lines', $geometry)` instead of selecting the first feature using `[0]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QGIS expression with overlay-fuction: filter-condition based on comparison of attributes from two layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391120/qgis-expression-with-overlay-fuction-filter-condition-based-on-comparison-of-at)

Comment: When you say a m x n relationship, what do you mean? Are you saying that multiple points and multiple lines can have the same ID? But only one point is on a given line with the same ID?

Comment: Yes, @TomBrennan. Multiple lines and multiple points with same ID. This note was to avoid people from trying to answer with `get_feature`, I must use `overlay_nearest` (because of the mxn relationship) AND use an id filter because of overlapping lines. (Both location and id matter) - Lines and points with same ID don't overlap, but lines and points with different IDs may overlap exactly.

Comment: @TomBrennan, I have a feeling that might answer my question indeed, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an ideal world, you'd just be able to declare a variable - the line ID - and then refer to that in the `overlay_nearest` function for the point layer. Unfortunately that doesn't work!

```
with_variable('lineId',"ID",
    line_locate_point(
        overlay_nearest('Lines', @geometry, filter:="ID"=@lineId)[0], 
    @geometry)
)
```

There is a feature request open in QGIS (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43146), so it may become available at some point in the future.

However, what we can do, as per [QGIS expression with overlay-fuction: filter-condition based on comparison of attributes from two layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391120/qgis-expression-with-overlay-fuction-filter-condition-based-on-comparison-of-at), is to wrap the `overlay_nearest` function in an `eval` call. Clunky, but necessary for now.

So rewriting the expression above, you get:

```
with_variable('lineId',"ID",
    line_locate_point(
        eval( 'overlay_nearest( \'Lines\', @geometry, filter:="ID"=' || @lineId || ' )' )[0],
    @geometry)
)
```

I tried to mock up some data similar to yours. This expression worked on that, though I'm not certain I fully understand your data (I get the m-n bit, but not sure about how your lines/points can overlap). Feel free to post a cut down sample set in your question.

As Daniel Möller points out, by using the `eval`, the `with_variable` expression is redundant and you can shorten it to:

```
line_locate_point(
    eval( 'overlay_nearest( \'Lines\', @geometry, filter:="ID"=' || "ID" || ' )' )[0],
@geometry)
```

Comment: This works, but we can get rid of the `with_variable` in this case. The `eval`  can use `"ID"` instead of `@lineId`- I suggest this edit to your answer

Comment: I'll add it as an alternative. The main reason to keep the `with_variable` section is that if in the future you can get rid of the `eval`, then you'd still need something declared outside the `overlay_nearest` to use in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the $id from die line layer as filter:

```
 line_locate_point(
    overlay_nearest(
    layer:='Lines',expression:=$geometry,filter:=$id=1)[0], 
    $geometry)
```

If you have a dedicated related ID in Point an Line you don't need `overlay_nearest` I think:

```
   with_variable('LineGeom',
    aggregate(layer:='Lines', 
        aggregate:='collect', 
        expression:=$geometry, 
        filter:="LineID" = attribute(@parent,'PointID')),
    line_locate_point(@LineGeom, $geometry))
```

Comment: The issue is that the id needs to be variable, not just 1. See this answer for why this is problematic: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/391120/qgis-expression-with-overlay-fuction-filter-condition-based-on-comparison-of-at

Comment: I've tried it like in the link. But i posted an additional approach the could be a little bit easier in this case if you avoid overlay.

Comment: If I already know which line is intersectig, I don't need it overla anymore or i misunderstand something.