# Why doesn't with_variable work in this QGIS expression?

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression

I'm trying to make a filter inside an `overlay_nearest` function where I must relate an attribute from the current layer to the overlay layer.

I'm trying to use `with_variable` to store the outer layer attribute, but for a weird reason it's not working. Can someone shed some light on how to make it work?

This is the expression I'm using (where `"ID"` is an integer):

```
with_variable(
    'myId', 
    "ID", 
    overlay_nearest(
         'Lines', 
          $geometry, 
          filter:="ID"=@myId
    )
)
```

The expression above returns an array with 0 elements, but any of the expressions below work ok:

This shows that `with_variable` seems to be working correctly as it returns the expected ID -> 80000.

```
with_variable('myId', "ID", @myId)
```

This shows that using the filter with a correct ID also works, as it returns 1 element in the array

```
with_variable(
    'myId', 
    "ID", 
     overlay_nearest(
         'Lines', 
          $geometry, 
          filter:="ID"=80000
     )
)
```

So, if `@myId` has the correct value (80000), and filtering with `"ID"=80000` works as expected, why does filtering with `"ID"=@myId` not work?

Comment: @tom-brennan posted a link to your last Q in the comments you can find two links in which could explain it https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/45744 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43146

Comment: I tried  with_variable() yesterday on your other Q and it didn't work for me with_QGIS Version 3.34.3-Prizren

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my answer at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/477802/129409

Basically, it's a limitation in QGIS. There is a feature request open (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43146), so it may become available at some point in the future.

In the meantime, the workaround is to wrap the `overlay_nearest` function in an `eval` call.

So rewriting your expression, you get:

```
with_variable('myId',"ID",
    eval( 'overlay_nearest( \'Lines\', $geometry, filter:="ID"=' || @myId || ' )' )
)
```

Comment: Your answer works, but I found out that in this case we can even avoid the usage of `with_variable`, replacing `@myId` with the actual `"ID"` field. The only purpose of the `with_Variable` was to try to achieve this in the first place.

Comment: That's interesting @DanielMöller - does raise questions of how `with_variable()` variables are handled by functions that access other layers. It's the same process, first resolve the value of `"ID"` then apply it to `overlay_nearest()`, but it seems like `"ID"` has to be evaluated as part of a larger expression inside out, rather than stored as a variable.

Comment: @she_weeds - it doesn't seem to matter whether it's a `with_variable()`, or just a sub-expression. If it involves other layers, `overlay_*` doesn't seem to handle it as expected. Pretty sure using a variable (or sub-expression) generally works ok with other semi-complex parent expressions like `aggregate`.