Connect ends of parallel line features to form polygons
I have a shapefile consisting of many sets of parallel line features. Each set has a unique ID. I want to close the ends of each set of parallel lines and create polygons. Is there a way to do this besides using the vertex editor to close each one manually? There is a couple thousand of these sets of lines so I would rather not do it manually. I'm using QGIS though I do have access to ArcGIS Pro.


Do you have an advanced license for ArcGIS Pro? Do you have any python ability?

Any chance of a sample shapefile for us to experiment with? I have some ideas but it'll take me time to make some sample lines to work on. Do your sets of lines ever cross (ie does one pair of lines ever cross over another pair)? Are separate pairs ever closer to another pair than the separation distance? Is the separation distance fairly constant across all features? Are the lines all valid LINESTRING simple features with no self-intersections (loops)?

I have OK python ability, and an academic license for ArcGIS pro. I also have access to the old ArcMap if that's useful.

No the sets of lines never cross each other. I don't think there are any instances where a pair of lines is closer to another pair than to each other, but it's possible. The separation distance is not constant across the features, but it never exceeds ~15 meters or so. I'll try to upload a sample shapefile

And perhaps I should mention that I just need to fill in the space between the lines for display purposes only. I don't need to be able to perform any kind of analyses with the polygons. Not sure if that makes a difference for how to approach this

Here is a sample portion of my shapefile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16nKpBUqJUWX4eFdT8aPka5XtyvRmICfT/view?usp=sharing

Oh and one more thing Spacedman, I noticed that some of the lines do have self-intersections :/



Geometry by expression to create a point layer of the line start and endpoints: collect_geometries( start_point( $geometry), end_point($geometry))

Output is a multipoint layer. Covert them to singleparts with Multipart to Singleparts

Shortest line between features with the singlepart output as both source and destination layer. Max number of neighbors = 2, set a maximum distance just above the distance between two parallel lines.

Merge your start layer with the shortest lines.

I had to Fix geometries

Dissolve with keep disjoint features separate = True.

Lines to Polygons:




Thanks Bera, it looks like this would work except I'm finding that there are quite a few instances in my shapefile where the separate pairs are closer to another pair than the lines are to each other

Yes, thats going to cause problems. Maybe you can set max number of neighbors to three, and then join attributes by location and extract the correct lines by attributes

This is not a complete answer - it's a modification of @Bera's Step 3 (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/484839/129409) for creating the end lines, to try to deal with some of the edge cases. It's somewhat complicated to explain, hence why I have not just added it as a comment.
You can use the fact that your sets of offset lines have unique IDs ("New_ID" field in your dataset) to restrict the creation of the shortest lines to the same set, by using Geometry by expression. By itself this is not quite enough, because when the lines are very short, the closest point is not the one on the offset line, but on the other end of the same line. In theory you can add the "Location" field into the filter expression, but I couldn't get this to work - possibly due to it being a text field. Instead, I created a new numeric "location2" field (0 for Lower, 1 for Upper), and this seemed to get around the issue.
The overlay_nearest function should give you the closest point, but has trouble with filters and operating on the same layer. However, you can trick it by wrapping the whole function in an eval. See here for more information: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415248/129409
So this expression uses the ID and location fields to find the nearest point with the same ID ("New_ID") and different location ("location2", created as above), and then makes a line to it.
with_variable('parent_id',"New_ID",
with_variable('parent_location',"location2",
    make_line($geometry, 
    eval('overlay_nearest(\'Single parts\',$geometry,filter:="New_ID"='||@parent_id||' AND ("location2"<>'||@parent_location||'),limit:=1)')[0]
)))


There are a few anomalies, but most of these seem to be due to the underlying data (eg you have duplicates of 118 and 119).

Here is one example where this logic does not work - when the end point of one line is closer to the start point of another. If your lines were consistently generated, you might be able to add an extra field, and condition to the filter


Looking into this without QGIS at hand, so just sharing some thoughts : couldn't one logic be to join the starting point of one part with ID X to the starting point of the other part with ID X, except if these linrs intersect, in which case connect the start to endpoints ? This would remove all dependencies to proximity/nearest conditions. Test for the intersection, then make one type of line or the other one depending on the test result.

Thank you Tom Brennan. I think this will get me close enough and then I can manually edit the handful of edge cases where it doesn't work!

@Kasper - if you can come up with an expression/method for that logic, it seems like it would work with no (or fewer) edge cases.
